# Saving JFreeChart chart to a specific directory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jfreechart

Is there a way to use JFreeChart to save to a specific directory rather than

```
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG("image.png", chart, 600, 300);
```

saving to the current directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting a full image path in your filename string rather than just "image.png"?

```
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("C:/\path/\to/\picture/\folder/\image.png"), chart, 600, 300);
```

Comment: Yes I tried that and I received an error saying : 'Severe:   java.io.IOException: No such file or directory'. The file does exist though. I tried to post the stack trace but it was too long to fit in the comment.

Comment: How about:
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("C:/\path/\to/\picture/\folder/\image.png"), chart, 600, 300);

Comment: I've updated the answer with my previous suggestion so it's easier to read, try it with a new File and pass your file path into that

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and now I'm receiving a file not found exception (Severe:   java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../../../../web/resources/images/imageA.png (No such file or directory))

Comment: There is a solution here, you can change the temp directory it saves to: http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9248. Or you could experiment with "writeToPNG" and provide it an output stream to the desired file

Comment: Thanks @dahui, I really appreciate your help! I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to save a chart to a png file by doing it in the following way:

Step 1: create a png file and make sure it exists.

```
File f = new File(filepath+"image.png");
if(!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();
```

Step 2: now that you're sure that the file exists, can you write the chart data to it:

```
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(f, chart, 800, 400);
```

If the file already exists will it be overwritten by this method.

As you're dealing with files, you need to add some try-catch statements to handle exceptions.